# I would like to know how I do to know that a div, spam, etc ... changes only the text

Tags: jquery, text, spam

I have tried with DOMSubtreeModified but the span has a data that every time it changes it throws the event to me. How can I isolate just the change in text from spam?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `MutationObserver` interface which provides the ability to watch for changes being made to the DOM tree. It is designed as a replacement for the older Mutation Events feature, which was part of the DOM3 Events specification.

The `MutationObserver` Creates and returns a new MutationObserver which will invoke a specified callback function when DOM changes occur so in the callback you can actually check what was the type that of the mutation that was changed.

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type); // will log the type that was changed
    });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true }

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

More about `MutationObserver` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver